# Old movie set in a dark city where a boy with a sword is searching for something

Tags: story-identification, movie

It has to have been made in either the 70’s or 80’s.  I think a young boy with a sword is the protagonist.  May be accompanied by a dwarf or troll.  Set in a dark city that always looks wet.  Could also have a cave or mountains around.  People may have talked with a British accent?  Maybe American?  Can’t remember. He’s searching for...something?

I remember it being a great movie.

Comment: Hi welcome to SF&F!  You might want to check out the [guide to writing a good question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) to see if there are any ideas there that might trigger some more memories.  Did you see it in a theatre?  On TV?

Comment: Any bits and pieces you can remember, if you can describe them, can help.